# fopen with correct file format and path

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment

How do I get to read my file with increment .htm  file with correct file format and path?

```
path:DATA\WEBPAGE_SOURCE\train75_phish_data\1.htm
file:1.htm,2.htm,3.htm....etc
```

Inside 1.htm,2.htm,3.htm....etc are the soucre code of webpage

I do try with the following example, but got the error when i=21.

```
data2=fopen(strcat('DATA\WEBPAGE_SOURCE\train75_phish_data\',int2str(i),'.htm'),'r')
```

I have refer to this, still cannot work, any ideas?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html

Here is my code:

```
data = importdata('DATA/URL/trainURL')
domain_URL = regexp(data,'\w*://[^/]*','match','once')

[sizeData b] = size(domain_URL);

for i = 1:150
A7_data = domain_URL{i};

data2=fopen(strcat('DATA\WEBPAGE_SOURCE\train75_phish_data\',int2str(i),'.htm'),'r')

CharData = fread(data2, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData
img_only = regexp(CharData, '<img.*?>', 'match');

feature7_data=(cellfun(@(n) isempty(n), strfind(img_only, A7_data))) 
B7(i)=sum(feature7_data)


end

feature7(B7>=10)=1;
feature7(B7<10&B7>5)=0;
feature7(B7<=5)=-1;

feature7'
```

Here is my output:

```
data = importdata('DATA/URL/trainURL') is a list of URL being saved inside
```

I could not loop the results for i=20, it will come to error when iteration=21, I want to loop until 150, it cnt read the 'data2' for 'i=21'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not use `importdata` if you are trying to read the webpages saved as htm files? You would be getting file identifier only into `data2`.

Comment: because importdata got limitation, my '1.htm' is the source code which may include thousands of line, Matlab stop running when I use importdata, I have go through this " data2=fopen(strcat('train75_phish_data\',int2str(i),'.htm'),'r')", which can run but my answer is not correct.

Comment: Look into `textscan` for reading large text files (html files are text files anyway) in chunks [here](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/examples/reading-arbitrary-format-text-files-with-textscan.html)

Comment: What exactly did you do, what were you expecting to happen, and what error did you get? You need to help us more than "still cannot work". Note that you are trying to open a file called `1`, not `1.htm`. This may be one problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to handle possible exceptions that can come in a more principled way. Try this:

```
data = importdata('DATA/URL/trainURL')
domain_URL = regexp(data,'\w*://[^/]*','match','once')

[sizeData b] = size(domain_URL);

for i = 1:150
   A7_data = domain_URL{i};    
   filename = fullfile('DATA\WEBPAGE_SOURCE\train75_phish_data\',strcat(int2str(i),'.htm'));
   if (exist(filename,'file')),
      disp(sprintf('file %s exists, processing it',filename));        
      data2=fopen(filename,'r');
      CharData = fread(data2, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData    
      fclose(data2);
      img_only = regexp(CharData, '<img.*?>', 'match');    
      feature7_data=(cellfun(@(n) isempty(n), strfind(img_only, A7_data))) 
      B7(i)=sum(feature7_data)
   else,
      disp(sprintf('file %s does not exist, skipping it!',filename));        
   end
end

feature7(B7>=10)=1;
feature7(B7<10&B7>5)=0;
feature7(B7<=5)=-1;

feature7'
```

after the line that does the fread.

Comment: I have tried added, it show me "??? Error using ==> fread
Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Error in ==> f7 at 11
    CharData = fread(data2, '*char')';  %read text file and store data in CharData"

Comment: @user3340270: Can you try restarting matlab? If the error persists after restarting, the file probably doesn't exist.

Comment: I have restarted my Matlab, it still return me the same error, I also have delete all my workspace and re-run also the same...